# Part of speech tagging Web Service?

Tags: web-services

I am looking for some POS tagging web-service. There are many solutions available (mostly in java) that can be integrated but I couldn't find an online service that could do the job. 
My problem statement is really simple, I want to send a single word and get back what part of speech it is e.g. Noun, Verb, Adjective etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to send a single word and get back what part of speech it is e.g. Noun, Verb, Adjective etc.

This is impossible, in English.

A part of speech method would have to take the whole sentence into account to determine the parts of speech of the words.

Some English words are homonyms.  They have to be interpreted in context.

```
Billy read the book.
```

read, verb

```
Billy, please give the book to Read.
```

Read, noun.

```
Billy, please give the book to Susie to read.
```

read, verb.

Comment: but there are many cases that do not have such ambiguity... e.g. 'beautiful', 'happy', 'amazing' they are all adjectives..similarly, 'baseball', 'chair', 'table' these are all nouns..and it doesn't require any context to understand this. There already are POS tagging facilities avaialble like Wordnet..I need this as a webservice though

Comment: Chair and table can also be verbs.  Any word in the English language can be a girl's name (noun).

Comment: 'Anything' could indeed be 'anything' in any language...but there are a few rules that are usually followed...and POS taggers provide support to figure out such stuff...